# Check if properties have value using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

How can I check if any `value` property has value?

```
[
  {
    "name": "DESIGEMPRESA",
    "value": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "DSP_DIRECAO",
    "value": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "MES",
    "value": ""
  }
]
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use `Array#some` to check if at least one element hasn't empty `value` value.

```js
var arr = [
  {
    "name": "DESIGEMPRESA",
    "value": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "DSP_DIRECAO",
    "value": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "MES",
    "value": ""
  }
],
res = arr.some(v => v.value != ''); //no object with not empty value

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 3):

There is _.isEmpty() in lodash

```js
    const a = [
      {
        "name": "DESIGEMPRESA",
        "value": ""
      },
      {
        "name": "DSP_DIRECAO",
        "value": ""
      },
      {
        "name": "MES",
        "value": ""
      }
    ]
    
    const r = a.map(x => _.isEmpty(x.value))
    
    console.log(r)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: little late, but I think this is the best if you're trying to map through the array and use this check to display individual properties

Answer (score 3):

You don't need lodash:

```
arr.some(obj => Boolean(obj.value))
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var arr = [
  {
    "name": "DESIGEMPRESA",
    "value": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "DSP_DIRECAO",
    "value": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "MES",
    "value": "d"
  }
]

var out = arr.filter(function(obj){
  return obj.value
})

console.log(out)
```

Comment: What if all elements have empty value?

Comment: @Kinduser out.length will be 0

Comment: I bet OP wants to return `true/false`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `_.find(collection, [predicate=_.identity], [fromIndex=0])`
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#find

```
  let x = [
    {
      "name": "DESIGEMPRESA",
      "value": "tr"
    },
    {
      "name": "DSP_DIRECAO",
      "value": ""
    },
    {
      "name": "MES",
      "value": ""
    }
  ]

  _.find(x, (o) => o.value.length > 0);
```

returns `{name: "DESIGEMPRESA" , value: "tr"}`

https://runkit.com/csprance/5904f9fcad0c6400123abaa2